# Informix future

Tags: informix

I am working on a system that runs with Informix and so I started learning more and more about Informix. I thinking on studying and getting the Informix certification.

Do you think there is future on Informix out there? Or should I try learning more about Oracle or MySQL or some other popular database system?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm biassed - I've been working with Informix since 1986, and for Informix since 1990.

I think there is an ongoing future for Informix.  Subject to the normal vagaries of predicting the future, and allowing for extra uncertainty because of the current economic conditions, I still expect to be working on or with Informix in 5 years; I think I'll probably be doing so in 10 years.

However, it is worth knowing about more than one DBMS, just as it is worth knowing about more than one operating system and worth knowing more than one programming language.  Therefore, I certainly couldn't fault you for also learning about other DBMS.

KillingMichael makes an interesting point about popularity, rates and travel.  There is likely to be some correlation.  It also depends on what sort of job you are after - whether you're looking for contracting work with regular to frequent changes of job, or whether you are looking for more stable employment.

Which other DBMS to learn is a complex decision.  I'm not sure whether SQLite and GoogleAppEngine are likely to have sufficiently few developers that you can get a jump ahead of the other people.

Answer (score 3):

Since you asked for advice :)

1: Pick what you like better.  As there is a future for Informix, Oracle and MySQL.  And, the best futures come from working in/with tools you love.

2: A general rule of thumb: if you work in less "popular" tools, then your rates go up BUT so does your travel.

3: [IMHO] However: If you're willing dive in head deep into something to master it, my personal recommendation would be to select something newer.  Like: SQLite, GoogleAppEngine, etc.  Something where you can get ahead of the other 100,000 or so other people that already have that particular skill set.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record - I know of companies that are having to employ people around the world to work remotely because they cannot find local or even national people with excellent local Informix skills.

There are very few new applications being developed around IDS - at least partly because IBM see it as legacy and do not promote it, even though they continue to develop it, a little.

And because there are very few new applications being developed using IDS (and more being ported to Oracle etc) very few people are skilling up on it. So as the previous posters said - Do it if you really want to, but avoid putting all your eggs is one basket - and be prepared to travel or work remotely.

Answer (score 2):

What I am missing it what area of Informix you are working with. Informix as a DBA/Admin, or Informix as a software developer. If the latter I would say move on. I have been a Informix Developer for 12 years using 4GL (and SPL) and no one wants to develop in these anymore. I am retraining over to Oracle. That said, there is no reason Informix as a database server does not have a future. Problem is it is viewed as a legacy system (and likely is) if you have one.  Reason it's not up there anymore is because IBM suck at marketing. And there approach to replacing it's primary language 4GL was too "buy" Genero which is just a pretty face wrapped around the old 4GL language. Compare that to Oracle with Java. Or SQL Server and C#. "Informix and 4gl/Genero" hmm. Even as a developer of it id never go there as a business. So how do they expect anyone else to who most haven't even heard of Informix. They need to get in bed with a real contender language and do some real marketing to get Informix taken serious as a DB server, as I think it is up there and id choose it over MS Server.

Paul@ If you know companies needing Informix developers, I'll happily put my Oracle career on hold! ;)

Comment: Thanks. My question was about developing in Informix and it was done 4 years ago! (not sure if you noticed).
I have moved on and I am doing other stuff these days.
Informix is still alive and used in many banks all over the world. The reasons they are stil using Informix are:
1. They don't want to pay billions for oracle licenses.
2. Too much expertise from their staff.
3. Too complicate systems and so they are afraid of the migration.